# Can someone explain how a code like this would look like and why it works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing this project on udemy and I have compared my code to the solution but they do not match at all. Can someone tell me what the most efficient line of code would look like for this problem (collatz_conjecture)?

```py
def collatz(n):
    if n > 1 and n %2 == 0:
        return (n/2)
    elif n > 1 and n %2 != 0:
        return (n*3+1)


print(collatz(3))
```

Comment: what does python if you enter 0?

Comment: I have tried to explain it in my answer @Markelo please check below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code is doing is that If the number is greater than 1 and is even, return the number after dividing it by 2, else if it is greater than 1 and odd, multiply the number by 3, add 1 to it and return.

For 3, the answer will be 10, since 3 is odd and 3*3+1=10. For 4 answer will be 2 since 4 is even and 4/2=2

Also from the wiki definition and your question, seems like you want to verify [collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), for which you need recursion to finally reach 1 for any positive integer, which can be done like so. Note the integer division `n//2` to ensure we pass integer for every recursive call

```
def collatz(n):
    #If n reaches 1 return it
    if n == 1:
        return 1

    #Based on n being even or odd, call the function recursively
    if n %2 == 0:
        return collatz(n//2)
    else:
        return collatz(n*3+1)

print(collatz(3))
#1
print(collatz(33))
#1
```

Comment: The line `elif n >= 1:` is not needed.